# Modsecurity SQL injection rule working only on quoted input value

Tags: owasp, mod-security

Recently I have configured modsecurity in my php application and while checking sql injection attack it behaves weird on one scenario. I was using REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf file with rule id 942100

It prevents the form submission(which was suppose I expected) if I give input as
SELECT * from users WHERE name='test'

It fails on other scenario if I give input without quotes or simple select query without where condition
SELECT * from users WHERE id=1 | Select * from users

Scenario1(Working and it blocks my request):
[image]
[image]

Scenario2(Failed and not blocking the request and values saved in db):
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is in your log? And what is your question?

Comment: Hi @airween my question is modsecurity rule is working and blocking the request if I submit the form values with select/insert/update query, if single quotes is present in my query. On the other hand it was not blocking the request if I submit queries without any quotes.

Comment: Rule 942100 uses @detectSQLi operator, which uses libinjection. Seems that libinjection does not detect this as an injection. `$ ./sqli -cm -d "SELECT * FROM USERS"` gives an empty result (which means not detected), but `$ ./sqli -cm -d "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE user = 'test'"` gives a pattern.